# can I receive data from mobile device and print to local printer?

Tags: iphone, .net, windows, web-services, iis

I am developing mobile phone/tablet applications and came to a point that I need to print receipt from a mobile device. The receipt printer is connected to a Windows PC. I have little experience in Windows programming but I am not afraid to learn. I've heard about web services. I wonder if it could be the choice of communication between my mobile client and windows server.

If web service is a good idea, how could I print the data received from mobile device to the local printer?

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Leo

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the the mobile operating system im not sure about printer capabilities in android   but windows mobile shouldnt be a problem   ipad i think depends on the printer your using as theres a low amout of printer support although if the the app is client server based this could worked around on server side of things by having the server send the print request

edit:  this article my also help with printing to non airprint printers as well 
http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-20023976-233.html

Comment: I dont think so. The mobile device is talking to the webservice on the win-pc which then initiate the print. So it doesnt depend on the mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Why not **send the user a PDF** that they can download or receive in their email or simply given a short url so they can print whenever they want and are?

You can generate the PDF with fancy headers and coloring so it would be a little better than a simple "**print web page**".

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) for the .NET environment is the library I use and it's lovely for this kind'a things.